# You are running `create-react-app` 5.0.0, which is behind the latest release (5.0.1). No longer supported

Tags: reactjs

I am having a problem when trying to create react application.

First, I tried to create a react app by running `npx create-react-app my-app`
Then I got the error:

```
You are running `create-react-app` 5.0.0, which is behind the latest release (5.0.1).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App.

Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:
- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app

The latest instructions for creating a new app can be found here:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/
```

So I tried multiple steps to fix this:

1. Uninstalling the package:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

2. Clearing cache: tried both:

```
npx clear-npx-cache
npm cache clean -f
```

3. Specifing version:

```
npx create-react-app@latest your-app-name
```

But none of these are working